# Implementing OpenCV functions on an array of float on the GPU

Tags: c++, opencv, gpu

I have an array of pixels of format 32FC1(32-bit floating point with one channel)

```
float * image; // my original image on the GPU
float * image_d;
int size = row*col*sizeof(float);
cudaMalloc((void**)&f_d, size);
cudaMemcpy(image_d, image, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
```

Right now, I want to call the function `gpu::GaussianBlur` from OpenCV on `image_d`, but this function only accepts parameter of format `"GpuMat"`. Is there any way to convert an `array` of `float` on the GPU to `GpuMat`?

What I mean is, I don't want any memory copy to happen between CPU and GPU. I hope the OpenCV function can directly process the array on the GPU.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create `GpuMat` form your device pointer:

```
const size_t step = col * sizeof(float);
GpuMat mat(row, col, CV_32FC1, image_d, step);
```

This `GpuMat` will not free memory, you should call `cudaFree` manually.

Comment: This is what I need. Thanks a lot. By the way, how can I know this? I can't find it on the OpenCV documentation.